# How to solve the unused argument error in R

Tags: r

I am attempting the r4ds r programming book and I ran into the unused argument error message when doing this question:

3. Compare dep_time, sched_dep_time, and dep_delay. How would you expect those three numbers to be related?

```
flights %>%
  near((dep_time - sched_dep_time), dep_delay, tol = 1)
```

The error message is: Error in near(., (dep_time - sched_dep_time), dep_delay, tol = 1) :
unused argument (dep_delay)

Answer (score 0):

When using the pipe `%>%`, the object preceding the pipe is entered as a first argument to the function following the pipe. So what you did was:

```
near(flights, (dep_time - sched_dep_time), dep_delay, tol = 1)
```

Now, `near()` only takes x, y and tol as arguments, but you passed three arguments before `tol`. You probably wanted to evaluate the arguments given to `near()` in the `flights` environment so you don't have to write `flights$dep_time` etc.

You can do this using the `with()` function:

```
flights %>%
  with(near((dep_time - sched_dep_time), dep_delay, tol = 1))
```

`flights` is now passed as a first argument to `with`. This is equivalent to the following:

```
with(flights, near((dep_time - sched_dep_time), dep_delay, tol = 1))
```